# Need to identify element

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is some HTML code, in which I need to find the element with the content `win8` (last element, `<div class="desc">win8</div>`).

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="display: block; z-index: 5002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 800px; top: 7px; left: 537px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-1">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="multi-wizard instance-wizard ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 518px;">
<div class="progress">
<form novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="steps">
<div class="step setup loaded" wizard-step-id="setup" style="display: none;">
<div class="step select-iso loaded" wizard-step-id="select-iso" style="display: block;">
<div class="wizard-step-conditional select-template" style="display: block;">
<div class="main-desc">
<div class="template-select content tab-view ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<input type="hidden" value="XenServer" name="hypervisor" wizard-field="hypervisor">
<div id="instance-wizard-featured-templates" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
<div class="select-container">
<div class="select **even**">
<input type="radio" name="templateid" wizard-field="template" value="b0c24832-6fdf-11e4-a45f-b6eb114441ae">
<div class="select-desc">
</div>
<div class="select **odd**">
<input type="radio" name="templateid" wizard-field="template" value="7720cdb2-b81a-4839-94cd-b56b660e3324">
<div class="select-desc">
<div class="name">win8</div>
<div class="desc">win8</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following XPath:

```
.//*[@id='instance-wizard-featured-templates']/div/div[2]/input
```

The issue is the screen has 2 elements, even and odd. Each time it loads it swaps the values. So the XPath selects the wrong element.

Is there a way to exactly select `win8`?

Comment: What does it mean "it swaps the values" ? What does it mean "exactly select win8" ? Also it seems like you have too few closing `</div>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always want to get the element with the class named 'desc', the correct XPath is looks like this:

```
//div[@class="desc" and text()="win8"]
```

This selects all `<div>` elements having the class 'desc' and 'win8' as text.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastin...can we use the word "and" in xpath?  It says syntax error and delete tokens

Comment: According to the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-logical-expressions) it is allowed and a quick test in the Firebug command line via [`$x('//div[@class="desc" and text()="win8"]')`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/$x) returns the element for me.

Comment: even i tried in firebug console and it identifies..but when i enter in eclipse ide it showed the above error

Comment: Where in Eclipse do you get that? Note that Eclipse just has ECMAScript 3 support and often has problems interpreting JavaScripts. Did you try that XPath in your Selenium script?

Comment: @sebastin the double quotes u specified must be replaced by single quotes...it works fine now.. Thanks a ton :)